# How to detect device if its Android or IOS in AMP

Tags: amp-html, browser-detection, amp-access

Could you please help me?
I´m using AMP by Google and i need to know if its Android or IOS to display different content One link for android devices another link for iOS devices

I've tried to use `amp-access` tag but I can not get the `user-agent`,  Do you have some examples? or Do you know how can i get it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead using AMP for this, try to write a rule within your htaccess file to detect user agent and then redirect based on said user-agent to the /amp/ variation of the page